# Responsive sidebar push menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one question about responsive sidebar menu. First off all i will give you a **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VLKamE)** from codepen.io

If you change your bowser width then you can see the green button on the top right side. When you click this button then the red background color div will open. But at the same time if you change your bowser width like `640px` to `900px` then red color div not come back original area.

How can i fixed it anyone can help me in this regard ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="test_container">
  <div class="left">
      <div class="left_in"><div class="aa">ss</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="r click_open_close">Click To Show Slide sLeft In</div>
  <div class="right"><div class="bb"></div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test_container{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 980px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0588235) 0px 1px 1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  min-height: 140px;
}
.left{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-right: 1px solid #d8dbdf;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  transition: opacity 2s, width 2s, left 2s, font-size 2s, color 2s;
}
.left_in{
  z-index: 999 !important;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
  animation-duration: 0.9s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;
  animation-name: slideLeft;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(25rem);
    transform: translateX(25rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(15rem);
    transform: translateX(15rem);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.aa{
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
  /*background-color: #dfdfdf;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dddbd1,#d2dbdc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top,#dddbd1,#d2dbdc);*/
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
   border-radius:0%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
}
.click_open_close{
  right:0px;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:999;
  display:none;
}
.pp{
  right:0px;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:green;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.right{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 840px) {
  .left {
    left:-60%;
  }
  .secret {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .click_open_close{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.click_open_close').click(function() {
  $('.left').animate({
    left: "0%"
  }, 200);
  $('.right').animate({
    right: "-30%"
  }, 200);
});
```

Comment: You need to add a resize listening to your JS.

Comment: @SeanStopnik i don't know it. Can you give me a little example. Or can you tell me somthing about it ?

Comment: @innovation.. Can you explain bit more about it!! I din get your problem properly!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Dear the (Marco Castro) answer think is good but still not working. What i want to do.  Please come the chat room for me [Chat Room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78378/gri)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

 $('.click_open_close').click(function() {
   $('.left').animate({
     left: "0%"
   }, 200);
 });

 });

 $(window).resize(function(e) {
     var windoww = $(window).width();
     if(windoww < 840){
         location.reload(); //or set whatever animation you want to do for the sidebar gets back in place
     };
 });
```

Comment: The developer console said `Unexpected token ( ` from this line . `if(windowWidth < backToOriginal)function(){`

Comment: it would be a problem if when you re-size browser the page reloads and that what you can avoid the problem?

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me. I solved the problem with your think.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad i could help, if you believe it was good enough, feel free to accept the answer